# how to make a modal show using bootstrap in django

Tags: jquery, django, modal-dialog

i have a modal that contains a list and on the click button it must show the problem is that once i click the button the modal **doesn't show instead it display a shadow**

i know that by default the modal is hidden and i need jquery in order to make it show and display its content.

## update2.html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalCart" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!--Header-->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Your Result</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <!--Body-->
      <div class="modal-body">

        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Content</th>
                <th>User</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {% for folder in FilterRecords %}
            <tr align="center">
                <td>{{ folder.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ folder.FolderNum }}</td>
                <td>{{ folder.FolderTitle }}</td>
                <td>{{ folder.Type }}</td>
                <td>{{ folder.Content }}</td>
                <td>{{ folder.user}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}

          </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>
      <!--Footer-->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Checkout</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## base.html

```
<form class="form-inline" id = "folderSearch" method="GET" action="{% url 'search_folder' %}">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="عما تبحث؟" name="searchFolder" value="{{request.GET.searchFolder}}">

           {%include 'blog/update2.html' %}
            <a href="{% url 'update2'%}" class=" btn btn-danger confirm-search" title="Search" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCart" id="searchButton">search </a>
</form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){    
    $(document).on('click', '.confirm-search', function () {
      $('#modalCart').modal('show');
    });

  })

    </script>
```

Comment: you are referring the  link somewhere `{% url 'update2'%}` and also performing the  `click` event on  same `a`  Tag. I didnt get this what you wannna to try?

Comment: @Akhilendra i am referring the link to **update2** because its the name of the template were the modal exist.

after the user enter his input and click the search button or link it must show the modal with the results

Comment: You are  already included  `{%include 'blog/update2.html' %}`. So it  is automatic available in `base.html`.

Comment: so i changed the a tag to be a button and i  just include the template  but still no success

Comment: Are you sure your `jQuery` and `bootstrap` CDN/file are correct?

Comment: yes sir  i am sure